# Spark Installation | Unable to start spark slaves - asking password

Tags: hadoop, installation, apache-spark

I wanted to configure spark on my hortonwork cluster. I downloaded spark tar file and updated configuration on master and copied those configuration on slave machine.

I started my spark master successfully with below command.

./start-master.sh

but for stating slave it is asking for password.

Below are three  files that i have updated

**spark-defaults.conf**

spark.master            spark://masternode:7077

spark.serializer        org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer

**conf/slaves**

hduser@slave1.bigdata

hdsuer@slave2.bigdata

**spark-env.sh**

```
SPARK_JAVA_OPTS=-Dspark.driver.port=53411

HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/conf

SPARK_MASTER_IP=hadoop-master.bigdatacoe

SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=4

SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8081
```

**I am able to ssh to slave node without password but still while starting spark slaves , it is asking for password.**

Please let me know what i am missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do `ssh hduser@slave1.bigdata` and `ssh hduser@slave2.bigdata` work (same host name and user)?

Comment: what process you followed in order to allow password-less SSH access from the master to slaves?

Comment: @G Quintana : ssh is working perfectly . It is not asking for password from Master node but while starting spark slave(./sbin/start-all.sh) , it is asking for password.

Comment: @kaktusito : I created ssh private and public keys using ssh-keygen and transferred public key to slave and given permission to file. I believe its a normal procedure that we follow while establishing ssh password less connection.

Comment: @Shashi You mentioned in a comment above that *while starting spark slave(./sbin/start-all.sh) , it is asking for password*. Maybe I misunderstood, but anyway, are you running start-all.sh from the master or from the slaves? You should run it only once in the master (and you should see in the logs initializing the slaves).

Comment: @kaktusito : I am running command from master. After firing command master is getting started successfully and log will be generated for the same but as soon as it is trying to start slave it will prompt for password and no log will be generated.

Comment: @Shashi Did you change the permission of the .ssh directory in the slaves also? (e.g. `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`).

Comment: @kaktusito . No . I haven't changed any permission for .ssh directory for any slave. I just checked it and it is 'drwx------' for master as well as slave.