# Spark workers asking for password

Tags: ssh, apache-spark

The question I am about to ask has already been asked, but there was no answer. Here is the link:
[Spark Installation | Unable to start spark slaves - asking password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005220/spark-installation-unable-to-start-spark-slaves-asking-password)

In my master computer (computer that will be the master), I have set the slaves file(which contains the ip of the worker computer i.e. 192.168.10.131), I have set the spark-env.sh file(export SPARK_MASTER_IP=192.168.2.57 and some other exports for cores and memory for the slave, still on the master computer). I also copied the spark-env.sh file to the worker computer in the spark/conf directory. I used ssh-keygen (on my master computer) and copied the appropriate file to the worker computer with `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub worker@192.168.10.131` (I executed this command from master computer), and now I can log in to the worker machine with ssh without password. When I finally execute ./start-all.sh script, it starts the master but asks for password when starting the worker (password for master@192.168.2.57, note that the username is the masters username and the ip is the worker`s ip). Did I do something wrong or something else is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, both computers had different usernames (master and worker). The trick is to use the same usernames i.e master for both computers.Just create a user on worker computer with same username and password as the master computer. That way when the worker asks for password you just login with the the master`s password. If someone has something to add, please do. Hope I helped!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have setup master ip as SPARK_MASTER_IP=192.168.2.57
Your worker ip is 192.168.10.131
When you say it asks password for (master@192.168.2.57) the ip is master's, not the worker's ip as you said. 
Most probably you have set **SPARK_LOCAL_IP** as master's ip address, hence it tries to create a worker in the master computer. 
Or you may have master's ip in the **slaves file** located at conf folder either as "localhost" or ip of master.
Hope this helps.